# adding multiple values in django path

Tags: django, parameters, hyperlink

I have the following paths set up:

```
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index"),
path('entry/<str:title>', views.entry, name='entry'),
]
```

my entry method is:

```
def entry(request,title):
entries = []
entry = util.get_entry(title)    
if entry != None:
    entries.append(entry)

return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
    "title": title,
    "entries": entries,
})
```

and in my html we have:

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>All Pages</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li>
     a href = "{% url 'entry' title=entry  %}" >{{ entry }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

two questions:

1. Is this the right way to pass parameters with a link?
2. What would I need to change to pass multiple parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the right way to pass parameters with a link?

**Yes**, by using the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) you calculate the path for a given view name and parameter(s).

There is however a small error in the HTML: you need to open the `<a>` tag, and furthermore not use spaces between the equal sign (`=`):

```
<a href="{% url 'entry' title=entry %}">{{ entry }}</a>
```

> What would I need to change to pass multiple parameters?

You define extra parameters in the view, for example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path('entry/<str:title>/<str:theme>/', views.entry, name='entry'),
]
```

and you specify values for the two parameters:

```
<a href="{% url 'entry' title=entry theme='mytheme' %}">{{ entry }}</a>
```

the view then takes three parameters:

```
def entry(request, title, theme):
    # …
```